# No suitable method found for parse(java.io.InputStream)

Tags: java, json

I wrote this in Java:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class Example1 {
 public static String readReddit()throws IOException, URISyntaxException {   

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(Example1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/reddit/redditdump.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        String kind = (String) jsonObject.get("kind");
        JSONArray data = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");

        System.out.println("Kind:" + kind);
        System.out.println("Data:");
        Iterator<String> iterator = data.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 return null;
}
```

with these dependencies in maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and I want to read from this JSON file:

```
[{
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
        "modhash": "",
        "children": [{
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "contest_mode": false,
                "banned_by": null,
                "media_embed": {

                },
                "subreddit": "PoliticalDiscussion",
                "selftext_html": "&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;The first Presidential Debate for the 2016 Elections will air tonight at 9:00PM Eastern at Hofstra University in New York. The debate will feature Donald Trump and Hillary Clinton in their first head-to-head televised debate. The debate will be 90 minutes and commercial free.&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;The Debate is hosted by the Commission on Presidential Debates and will be moderated by NBC’s Lester Holt. Hillary Clinton will &lt;a href=\"https://twitter.com/CBSNews/status/780506360257675264\"&gt;receive the first question&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;hr/&gt;\n\n&lt;h2&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Where to Watch&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/h2&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Unlike the primaries, these debates are hosted by the Commission on Presidential Debates and the broadcast is not restricted to one network, making for a wide range of viewing options. Here are just a few of the ways you can watch:&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Television:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;The event will be broadcast on most major TV channels, including ABC, CBS, CNN, C-SPAN, Fox News, MSNBC, and Univision.&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Live Streams:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.c-span.org/2016presidentialDebates/\"&gt;C-SPAN&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6QElWIKfDk\"&gt;Washington Post (YouTube)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuHuzhzb1nc\"&gt;PBS (YouTube)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=855Am6ovK7s\"&gt;NBC (YouTube)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://twitter.com/i/live/778347749217406976\"&gt;Bloomberg Politics (Twitter with real-time fact checking)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/ABCNews/\"&gt;ABC (Facebook)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;hr/&gt;\n\n&lt;h2&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Live Discussion&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/h2&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;If you&amp;#39;d like to participate in real-time discussion, we encourage you to head over to &lt;a href=\"https://discord.gg/caAhhCv\"&gt;our Discord server&lt;/a&gt; and check out our &lt;a href=\"https://discordapp.com/channels/154635757615710208/229738984618721280\"&gt;Presidential Debate Channel&lt;/a&gt;. &lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;hr/&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;Please use this thread to discuss your tonight&amp;#39;s debate as it happens. All subreddit rules still apply in live threads and in Discord, so please remember to remain civil and try to keep discussion quality high. &lt;strong&gt;This thread will be closely watched, and any rule violations are certain to be met with heavy-handed moderation. Be nice!&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;",
                "selftext": "The first Presidential Debate for the 2016 Elections will air tonight at 9:00PM Eastern at Hofstra University in New York. The debate will feature Donald Trump and Hillary Clinton in their first head-to-head televised debate. The debate will be 90 minutes and commercial free.\n\nThe Debate is hosted by the Commission on Presidential Debates and will be moderated by NBC’s Lester Holt. Hillary Clinton will [receive the first question](https://twitter.com/CBSNews/status/780506360257675264).\n\n-----\n\n**Where to Watch**\n-\n\nUnlike the primaries, these debates are hosted by the Commission on Presidential Debates and the broadcast is not restricted to one network, making for a wide range of viewing options. Here are just a few of the ways you can watch:\n\n**Television:**\n\nThe event will be broadcast on most major TV channels, including ABC, CBS, CNN, C-SPAN, Fox News, MSNBC, and Univision.\n\n**Live Streams:**\n\n[C-SPAN](https://www.c-span.org/2016presidentialDebates/)\n\n[Washington Post (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6QElWIKfDk)\n\n[PBS (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuHuzhzb1nc)\n\n[NBC (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=855Am6ovK7s)\n\n[Bloomberg Politics (Twitter with real-time fact checking)](https://twitter.com/i/live/778347749217406976)\n\n[ABC (Facebook)](https://www.facebook.com/ABCNews/)\n\n------\n\n**Live Discussion**\n-\n\nIf you'd like to participate in real-time discussion, we encourage you to head over to [our Discord server](https://discord.gg/caAhhCv) and check out our [Presidential Debate Channel](https://discordapp.com/channels/154635757615710208/229738984618721280). \n\n----------\n\nPlease use this thread to discuss your tonight's debate as it happens. All subreddit rules still apply in live threads and in Discord, so please remember to remain civil and try to keep discussion quality high. **This thread will be closely watched, and any rule violations are certain to be met with heavy-handed moderation. Be nice!**",
                "likes": null,
                "suggested_sort": "new",
                "user_reports": [],
                "secure_media": null,
                "saved": false,
                "id": "54nuut",
                "gilded": 0,
                "secure_media_embed": {                 
                },
                "clicked": false,
                "report_reasons": null,
                "author": "BagOnuts",
                "media": null,
                "score": 550,
                "approved_by": null,
                "over_18": false,
                "domain": "self.PoliticalDiscussion",
                "hidden": false,
                "num_comments": 8576,
                "thumbnail": "",
                "subreddit_id": "t5_2sfmf",
                "edited": 1474937730,
                "link_flair_css_class": "green2",
                "author_flair_css_class": "",
                "downs": 0,
                "archived": false,
                "removal_reason": null,
                "stickied": false,
                "is_self": true,
                "hide_score": false,
                "permalink": "/r/PoliticalDiscussion/comments/54nuut/debate_megathread_live_discussion_thread_for_the/",
                "locked": false,
                "name": "t3_54nuut",
                "created": 1474964458,
                "url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/PoliticalDiscussion/comments/54nuut/debate_megathread_live_discussion_thread_for_the/",
                "author_flair_text": "Extra Nutty",
                "quarantine": false,
                "title": "[Debate Megathread] LIVE Discussion Thread for the First Presidential Debate of 2016",
                "created_utc": 1474935658,
                "link_flair_text": "Presidential Debate",
                "ups": 550,
                "upvote_ratio": 0.83,
                "mod_reports": [],
                "visited": false,
                "num_reports": null,
                "distinguished": null
            }
        }],
        "after": null,
        "before": null
    }
},
{
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
        "modhash": "",
        "children": [{
            ..
```

but I get an error:

> Error:(132, 32) java: no suitable method found for
>   parse(java.io.InputStream)
>
> method org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(java.lang.String) is not applicable
>
> (argument mismatch; java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
>
> method org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(java.io.Reader) is not applicable
>
> (argument mismatch; java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to java.io.Reader)

I don't find where the issue is. Also I don't just want to print these results I get, but rather save them and use. I am not very much experienced in Java. Any help would be highly appreciated. Maybe I haven't imported any dependencies?

Comment: The issue is just as the error message says. There is no such file on your disk. The file is a relative one, so it's searched from the directory where you execute the `java` command used to start your program.

Comment: @JBNizet but there is such file in my disk. That's the issue!

Comment: Have you read my comment until the end? What's the absolute path of the directory from which you execute the java command? Whats the absolute path of the JSON file?

Comment: To see which file Java tries to read you can add `System.out.println(new File("data/reddit/redditdump.json").getAbsolutePath());` just before you try to open the file

Comment: @JBNizet I tried writing the absolute path of the directory, didn't work `/Users/myname/Desktop/javajson/src/main/resources/data/reddit/redditdump.json`

Comment: Is the code good though, am I reading correctly or ?

Comment: So, your code can only work if you execute your program from the `/Users/myname/Desktop/javajson/src/main/resources` directory. I doubt that's the case. Files stored under src/main/resources are meant to be bundled with the program itself, and loaded using the ClassLoader. not using file IO. What do you really want to do?

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to read just like I read these .csv files and return the content: 
 `public static String readTVdata()throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
 String tv_1 = readFile("data/csv/2016_09_26_first_presidential_fullraw.csv");
String tv_2 = readFile("data/csv/2016_10_09_second_presidential_fullraw.csv");
return tv_1 + tv_2;
}` Trying to do the same with this json data. And return it not just print it like I am doing rn.

Comment: Then read the code of the readFile() method to understand how it does it, and use the same technique.

Comment: @JBNizet you mean this one    `private static String readFile(String file) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        URI uri = Exercise1.class.getClassLoader().getResource(file).toURI();
        Files.lines(Paths.get(uri)).forEach(s::append);
        return s.toString();
    }`

Comment: Yes. As you can see, it uses the class loader to load the resource. You should really just use Exercise1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file) to load the contents as an InputStream.

Comment: @JBNizet I used that now like this: `Class<JSON1> classLoader = JSON1.class;
ile file = new File(classLoader.getResource("data/reddit/redditdump.json").getFile());`  but still I get an exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: That's incorrect. Stop thinking about this resource as a file. It won't be a file once you've bundled your program as a jar file. Again, use Exercise1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file) to get an InputStream, and pass that to your JSON parser.

Comment: @JBNizet okay. like this you mean  `Exercise1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/reddit/redditdump.json");` and then  `Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader..` or without FileReader?

Comment: No. Pass the InputSTream directly to your parse() method. Trying to pass an InputSTream to a FileReader can't possibly compile. If the parser really needs a Reader, and not an InputStream, then wrap the InputStream into an InputSTreamReader. You really need to take the time to read the javadoc of the classes and methods that you're using, to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, I understand! I don't think the parser needs a Reader, but rather just the InputStream. Do you mean like this: ` Object obj = parser.parse(Exercise1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/reddit/redditdump.json"));`

Comment: Yes. But again, you shouldn't "think". You should "know". By reading the javadoc of the parser you're using.

Comment: @JBNizet you're right. I get this: `Error:(135, 32) java: no suitable method found for parse(java.io.InputStream)
    method org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
    method org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(java.io.Reader) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to java.io.Reader)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Example1.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("data/reddit/redditdump.json").getFile());

Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
```

Comment: I get this error now : `Error:(132, 39) java: non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: @Gentsview then use ``JSON1.class`` instead of ``getClass()``

Comment: @f1sh tried that already and I get Error: `cannot be converted to java.lang.ClassLoader`

Comment: I changed it to `Class<JSON1> classLoader = JSON1.class;` it worked but I get another exception now `Class<JSON1> classLoader = JSON1.class;`

Comment: You need access to the classloader. Use ``ClassLoader classLoader = JSON1.class.getClassLoader();``.

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceAsStream` means that you have `InputStream` as returned object. And your exception is `no suitable method found for parse(java.io.InputStream)` means that method `parser.parse()` does not accept `InputStream`. You have to look at this method implementation and find out what type of objects accept this method and convert `InputStream` into one of it. I saw that at least `String` and `Reader` are acceptable and I convert `InputStream` to `Reader`:

```
public static String readReddit() {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(Example1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/reddit/redditdump.json"))) {
        ((JSONArray)parser.parse(reader)).forEach((Consumer<JSONObject>)obj -> {
            String kind = (String)obj.get("kind");
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject)obj.get("data");
            JSONArray children = (JSONArray)data.get("children");
            System.out.println("Kind: " + kind + ", total children: " + children.size());
        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```